# How do I test if provider credentials are valid in apache libcloud?

Tags: apache, openstack, libcloud

I was trying to create a driver for openstack using apache libcloud. It doesn't raise any error even if the user credentials are wrong. So When i checked the faq i found an answer as given in the link
[Apache libcloud FAQ](http://ci.apache.org/projects/libcloud/docs/faq.html)

But it doesn't seem to be effective since querying each time to check whether the user is authenticated will reduce the performance if the query returns a bulk of data.

When i checked the response i got from the api there is a field called `driver.connection.auth_user_info` and i found that the field is empty if the user is not authenticated. So can i use this method as a standard? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

An openstack driver for libcloud is already available:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

os = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK)
params = {'key': 'username', 'ex_force_service_region':'regionOne', 
   'ex_force_service_name':'nova', 'ex_force_auth_version':'2.0_password',
   'ex_force_auth_url':'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
   'ex_force_service_type':'compute', 'secret':'password',
   'ex_tenant_name':'tenant'}
driver = os(**params)
```

But libcloud does not check the credentials by just creating the `driver` object. Instead, the creds will be validated only when a request is sent. If the internal exception `InvalidCredsError` is thrown the credentials are invalid, and an own variable could be set:

```
from libcloud.common.types import InvalidCredsError

validcreds = False

try:
    nodes = driver.list_nodes()
    if nodes.count >= 0:
        validcreds = True
except InvalidCredsError:
    print "Invalid credentials"
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

I would not rely on the internal variable `auth_user_info` because it could change over time.

Comment: when there are many nodes for that user this query will be expensive right?

Comment: The solution you provided is already there in the FAQ link and i was asking for any better solution

Comment: By storing the result of your **first time** credential check, there is no need to repeat it **each time**. To reduce the response you can use any other command like `driver.list_sizes()`or `driver.list_images()`. Later you only check the variable, so you get a performance enhancement.

Comment: Okay. I was trying to memcache the driver object so that i can use it without querying it for each time. But it raises `expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found` and type of my object is ` <class 'libcloud.compute.drivers.openstack.OpenStack_1_1_NodeDriver'>
`